# How to iterate and change the value of each item in a priority queue in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

In java, I want to decrement the value of each element in a priority queue by 1.

This is a sample of some code of what I tried:

```
// more code

PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(size, Collections.reverseOrder());

// code that adds items to q

for (Integer item: q) {
   item--;
}
```

However it does not seem to change the priority queue items at all.
How do I fix this code so it does what I intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create another queue and populate it by adding decremented values from the first one:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(size, Collections.reverseOrder());
PriorityQueue<Integer> q2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(size, Collections.reverseOrder());

// code that adds items to q

for (Integer item: q) {
   q2.add(--item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand why it doesn't change the value of `item`. The reason is that `Integer` is an **immutable** class, meaning that once the class instance is assigned a value (int) it won't change. You can modify your loop statement to create a new `Integer` that has the decremented value or use the `AtomicInteger` class and its `getAndDecrement` method. The latter however has some synchronization overhead.

**Update with code samples**

```
PriorityQueue<AtomicInteger> q = new PriorityQueue<AtomicInteger>(size,  Collections.reverseOrder());

// code that adds items to q
for (AtomicInteger item: q) {
   item.getAndDecrement();
}
```

Comment: I think I understand as to "why" it was not working now, but not so much how to fix it. How would I modify my loop statement for it to work? I am tempted to write something like this `pancake = new Integer(pancake - 1);` but thats the same thing as I wrote before.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new `PriorityQueue<Integer>` and iterate over the first one like this:

```
Queue<Integer> newQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(); 

Iterator<Integer> itr = q.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Integer current = q.poll();
    // do some processing with current
}
```

As you can see we iterate over the `PriorityQueue<Integer>` simply using an `Iterator` and after you are done with your processing simply set the `newQueue` to your old variable or do all of that in a method and return your `newQueue`.

Answer (score 2):

Mutating objects within a PriorityQueue is likely to lead to inconsistent behavior. While the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) does not state this explicitly, it is hinted at by the fact that inserting elements is a O(log(n)) operation but getting the top of the queue (peek or element) without actually removing is constant time:

> Implementation note: this implementation provides O(log(n)) time for
>   the enqueuing and dequeuing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add);
>   linear time for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods; and
>   constant time for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size).

This seems to indicate that the elements are sorted at addition and expected to remain in that same sort order. Mutating objects within the queue in a way that impacts the comparison does not appear to be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand how PriorityQueue works.

```
public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity,
             Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that
>   orders its elements according to the specified comparator.

You cant't to increase priority in way you are using PriorityQueue. You only can change the priority by re-ordering elements in `q`.

Now, if you really want to have priorities as property of any object, you must define your own wrapper to object. For examlpe:

```
public class PriorityItem implements Comparable<PriorityItem> {

    private int priority;

    public PriorityItem() {
        this.priority = 0;
    }

    public PriorityItem(int priority) {
        super();
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PriorityItem obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.priority-obj.priority;
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
   PriorityQueue<PriorityItem > q = new PriorityQueue<PriorityItem >(20, new Comparator<PriorityItem>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(PriorityItem one, PriorityItem two) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return one.compareTo(two);
    }
```

Now you can loop over queue and change priority to your items:

```
for (PriorityItem item: q) {
   item.setPriority(item.getPriority() + 1);
}
```